# Docker compose with private registry

Tags: docker, docker-compose, registry, docker-registry

I have a problem with my docker compose. Maybe someone knows how to solve it.
I have created a private registry using docker, then I have create a custom image (based on debian) and pushed it to the private registry.

So, first of all I do the `docker login registry.domain.com` and then:

When I run a new container with the custom image:

```
docker run -it --name TEST registry.domain.com/debian:2 /bin/bash
```

It works fine, the container starts and I can use it.
But, when I use this docker compose:

```
version: "2.1"
services:
    TEST:
        container_name: TEST
        image: registry.domain.com/debian:2
        #environment:
        volumes:
            - ./config:/media/nextcloud
        ports:
            - 80:80
        restart: unless-stopped
```

The container does not start, it is restarting in bucle: `Restarting (0) 4 seconds ago`
Also, when I try to check the logs with `docker logs TEST` it does not show anything, 0 lines... (I have tried with the version 2.1 and 3)

Can someone help me with this please? I am out of ideas.

Regards,

Comment: I think the command is missing. The container doesn't know what he should execute.

Comment: which command? In the compose?

Comment: Yes, you missed the command: /bin/bash in your TEST service.

Comment: to be honest I have never added this into the compose and all of them worked fine...

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the image's Dockerfile?  With what you've shown, the image's `CMD` is running, and completing successfully (`(0)`), and then restarting.  You shouldn't normally need to override the `command:` in Compose, nor should you need the `/bin/bash` command in your `docker run` invocation.

Comment: what do you mean with the image's dockerfile? where can I get it? Meanwhile, I have ran the docker-compose with "docker-compose run --rm TEST" and it starts successfully, so the image should work fine. The problem is (like you said) the constant reboot...

Comment: Ok, "solved" adding the line "command: tail -F whatever" in the docker-compose. Looks like the Debian image by default stops when it finish with the tasks... So adding this line, the container will run forever and I am able to connect and change it.

Answer (score 0):

First a quick high level, a container is a wrapper around a process, configuring it with various namespaces and other Linux kernel isolation techniques. When that process exits, the container is gone. This is different from a VM that starts a kernel and then you connect to deploy applications in the VM.

Bash runs until reaching an exit or similar command, or stdin indicates the end of input (e.g. reaching the end of a shell script). With an interactive tty (`docker run -it`) that stdin is open until you close the terminal or run `<ctrl-d>` or something else to terminate the input.

With `docker compose`, that command never receives any input so it immediately exits. It's not unlike trying to run `docker run -i --rm debian </dev/null`, just `bash </dev/null` in Linux, or a shell script with a single line at the top `#!/bin/bash`.

You can keep the container running in various ways. One option is `tail -f /dev/null` instead of the shell, to do nothing in the background. However, most people start a container to do something, so that application / service should be what you run instead. It needs to be launched in the foreground so that the container remains waiting for it to exit.